# PHP create json with foreach loop

Tags: php, json

I want to prepare json with php as follows. But, the services section does not occur nested. How can I get json output as below by correcting php code?

```
foreach($this->input->post('name') as $key => $value){
    $services = [];
    foreach($this->input->post('services') as $value2){
        $services[] = array(
            'service_name' => $value2
        );
    }

    $json[] = array(
        'name'      => $this->input->post('name')[$key],
        'surname'   => $this->input->post('surname')[$key],
        'birthday'  => $this->input->post('birthday')[$key],
        'services'  => $services
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

I want this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"aa",
      "surname":"bb",
      "birthday":"10.07.2019",
      "services":[  
          {  
             "service_name":"test1",
             "service_name":"test2",
          },
       ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"cc",
      "surname":"dd",
      "birthday":"20.07.2019",
      "services":[  
          {  
             "service_name":"test3",
             "service_name":"test4",
          },
       ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Well the service name key should be unique in Php. In Php associative arrays have unique keys

Comment: Can you provide sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
foreach($this->input->post('name') as $key => $value){
    $services = [];
    $count = 0;
    foreach($this->input->post('services') as $value2){
        $services["service".$count] = $value2;
        $count++;
    }

    $json[] = array(
        'name'      => $this->input->post('name')[$key],
        'surname'   => $this->input->post('surname')[$key],
        'birthday'  => $this->input->post('birthday')[$key],
        'services'  => $services
    );
}
$json = json_encode($json);
$json = preg_replace('/"service\d+"/', "service_name", $json);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Thank you. But, it's not working. Because, service name must be written differently according to the corresponding value

Comment: Please post the output and also the expected output

Comment: Code Output:
    [  
       {  
          "name":"aa",
          "surname":"bb",
          "birthday":"10.07.2019",
          "services":{  
             "service_name":"test1",
             "service_name":"test2",
             "service_name":"test1"
          }
       },
       {  
          "name":"cc",
          "surname":"dd",
          "birthday":"09.07.2019",
          "services":{  
             "service_name":"test1",
             "service_name":"test2",
             "service_name":"test1"
          }
       }
    ]

Comment: I want this:
[
   {
      "name":"aa",
      "surname":"bb",
      "birthday":"10.07.2019",
      "services":[  
          {  
             "service_name":"test1",
             "service_name":"test2",
          },
       ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"cc",
      "surname":"dd",
      "birthday":"20.07.2019",
      "services":[  
          {  
             "service_name":"test3",
             "service_name":"test4",
          },
       ]
   }
]

Comment: sorry it gave the same output.

Comment: Please comment the second last line and post the output

Comment: Service names do not come according to the field.

Code Output: [ { "name":"aa", "surname":"bb", "birthday":"10.07.2019", "services":{ "service_name":"test1", "service_name":"test2", "service_name":"test1" } }, { "name":"cc", "surname":"dd", "birthday":"09.07.2019", "services":{ "service_name":"test1", "service_name":"test2", "service_name":"test1" } } ]

Comment: Well the output you posted includes the string "service_name", but in the code there is no "service_name". Did you comment out the second last line that contains preg_replace?

Comment: the only problem is that it does not write the corresponding code in the corresponding field in the code you provide

Comment: Please provide the output of print_r($this->input->post('name')) and print_r($this->input->post('services'))

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => aa
    [1] => cc
)

Comment: Please update your question so it includes the actual output